# How to run a script at startup before networking is enabled?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, kvm, bridge

I have a system that I use to test some programs doing non-IP networking protocols on various operating systems in virtual machines. The host is Fedora Linux. Because the networking is non-IP, the VMs need to be bridged to the physical ethernet interface. FOr reasons that I don't quite understand, this means that the bridge must be the primary network interface for the host machine. So I find that I need to

- take the host's eth0 down
- create the bridge br0
- add eth0 to the bridge
- do ipconfig on br0

For a long time, it worked for me to do this with commands in /etc/rc.local but recently (since Fedora 20?) that does not work any more.

1) Is there a way to configure this as part of the module configuration for the VM subsystem (in a way that can be done AFTER the system is installed) ? That would surely be my preference

2) How do I do this in more recent Fedora systems? It looks like systemd no longer runs /etc/rc.local (or /etc/rc.d/rc.local)

Answer (score 1):

I'd create this using the standard `network-scripts` files:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Create_a_Network_Bridge.html

This would allow `br0` to be created, and then the `ifcfg-eth0` file can be adjusted to use that.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `lmgrd` which is a system daemon

just create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/` ending with `.service` with this typed into it

```
[Unit]
Description="whatever you have in mind for its description"
Before=network.target
Wants=something-else.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart="direct it to whatever you want to execute here"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you could type `systemctl enable nameofyourservice` to enable it to start on boot

or just `systemctl start nameofyourservice` to start it

for more guidance you can read the man page